# Find all integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a + b =1 - c $, $a^3 + b^3 =1 - c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, integers

Find all integers a,b, and c such that: \begin{align*}a + b &= 1 - c, \\a^3 + b^3 &= 1 - c^2. \end{align*}
My approach is $(a + b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = (1 - c)(1+c)$, so one solution would be  $(a,b,c)=(k,-k,1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but if we then assume $a+b \neq 0$ then we get $a^2-ab+b^2 = 1+c$, and I am not really sure what to do from there.

Comment: Then you can have $a^2+2ab+b^2=(1-c)^2$, and $3ab=c^2-3c$, so $c = 3k$, $ab=3k^2-3k$, so $a,b$ solve $x^2-(1-3k)x+3k^2-3k=0$.

Comment: Please do not use displays in titles. It messes up rendering in some displays.

Comment: So $a^2 - ab + b^2 +a+b-2 = 0$, which is an ellipse with finitely many lattice points on it (so check small enough cases).

Comment: @CalvinLin  Well, it does if you can't read the $c^2$ and convert it to a $c^3$.    Really need to keep my glasses on.  Anyway, thanks.  I'll delete the incorrect solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $c = 1-a-b$ by the first equation, which we can plug into the second equation. So we just have one equation, namely
$$a^3 + b^3 + (1-a-b)^2 - 1 = 0$$
or equivalently
$$(a+b)(a^2+b^2+a+b-ab-2)=0$$
So there are two cases, $b=-a$ (hence $c=1$) and
$$a^2+b^2+a+b-ab-2 = 0$$
The latter describes an ellipse, which you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Ba%2Bb-ab-2%20%3D%200).

It is located in the interval $[-3,1] \times [-3,1]$, so there are not so many integers to check. The solutions are also clearly symmetric since the equation is symmetric in $a,b$. The solutions up to this symmetry are $(-3,-2)$, $(-2,0)$, $(0,1)$.